# Connecting microsoft sql server 2008 r2 to netbeans IDE 7.0 "error 18456 severity 14 state 38 login failed"

Tags: database, database-connection, netbeans-7, sql-server-2008-express, jtds

I have been working on this for last two days and I just can't finish it! I'm trying to add Microsoft Sql Server 2008 r2 to netbeans 7 by using Jtds or sqljdbc and none of them seem to work.
Both of them are giving me this error: "cannot establish a connection to jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.R0CRID3R using net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver (Cannot open database "C" requested by the login. The login failed.)  Login failed for user 'sa'."

I already enabled TCP/IP and opened the port 1433 and set the ports and set the login for mixed windows authentication and sql server authentication.
It gives me this error for either Jtds and sqljdbc.
The log from sql server management studio tells this:
"Source: Logon, Message: Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38
Source: Login, Message: Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified databes.[CLIENT: 127.0.0.1]"
I became really desprate by now. Any help would be much more than appriciated.
I also tried opening netbeans as administrator, and also tried restarting the database engine.
If there is any details I failed to write please ask and I'll tell it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I can add that database to Visual Studio easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug in Netbeans's installation. It wasn't fixed even after update. I uninstalled and downloaded the latest netbeans ide, which is 7.2.1, and when I tried it worked without any problems at all.